# Start Animating CSS Value at Specific Keyframe

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a block that I want to animate the `height` to 0, and then the `width` to 0. Is there a way to do that with a CSS animation?

The catch is that I don't know what the starting height/width of the block is, so using

```
@keyframes shrink {
    50% { height: 0; width: <UNKNOWN>; }
    100% { width: 0 }
}
```

doesn't work.

The effect I'm going for is like this (using jQuery): http://jsfiddle.net/andrewburgess/LFjEv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED TO THE ANSWER THAT WAS ACTUALLY ACCEPTED

you can animate with a delay. You just need to set the class via JS.
Sadly this cannot be done with keyframe animations if the width is dynamic

---

http://jsfiddle.net/LFjEv/4/

CSS

```
.block, .other-block {
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 200px;
}
.block {
    -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0ms, 500ms;
    -webkit-transition-duration:500ms;
    -moz-transition-property: height, width;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0ms, 500ms;
    -moz-transition-duration:500ms;
    transition-property: height, width;
    transition-delay: 0ms, 500ms;
    transition-duration:500ms;
}
.block.shrink {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}
.other-block {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

JS

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('.block').addClass('shrink');
}, 0);
```

Comment: The issue is that the width animates for the entire duration, instead of the second half of it.

Comment: I'm basically looking for: 0%-50% animate height, 50%-100% animate width, except that I don't necessarily know what the width is to fix it for the 0%-50% portion of the animation.

Comment: ah.. sorry. my mistake. You would have to trigger a class or the dimension via javascript. The you can use CSS transitions with a delay. Sadly I could not find a different solution (yet). but you can still use CSS transitions instead of jQuery.animate  http://jsfiddle.net/LFjEv/4/

Comment: If you have a child with the width it works without javascript. http://jsfiddle.net/LFjEv/6/

Comment: The `transition` method looks like it is ideal. Thanks for the different versions as well